# Can't access Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100) storage?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb-connection-mode

I'm using `Samsung Galaxy S2` and I was able to access its storage before. But now, it does not appear in `My Computer` anymore.

I tried reconnecting it and even restarted both the S2 and my PC but to no avail. However, when I typed `adb devices` on cmd, my device is listed there. In fact, the connector icon is also present on the notification bar of my device. I also tried switching the cable I'm using but it still did not work. Furthermore, the cable seems to be working with other devices. Other PCs won't also recognize my device.

I'm using a 32-bit Windows XP and the connection mode of my device is `MTP`. What could be the problem of my phone? How do I fix it?

Comment: On your device, go to the developer settings and disable *USB Debugging*. Then try again (some devices have trouble to connect in "drive mode" when *USB Debugging* is enabled). If that doesn't help: What else did (you) change between "once it worked" and "now it doesn't"?

Comment: Hi, @Izzy. Thanks for replying! I tried disabling USB Debugging earlier but it didn't fix my problem. After performing a factory data reset, my device is now working properly. :)

Comment: A factory-reset is not the most convenient solution -- but better than staying with the problem. So glad you've been able to solve the issue!

Comment: @Izzy: Yes. It's better than being stuck with the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to know what is the problem with my device. But after performing a factory data reset, it's now working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you encrypted your device storage? If no then just backup your all data and give it a factory reset. It should fix the problem. Had this problem with my s3 for two times. Now its' running fine.

Answer (score -1):

Also try a different USB cable.  Sometimes cables can be finicky.

Comment: This seems more of a comment, isn't that so?!

Comment: As adb works perfectly, it's unlikely to be the cable.